# How to remove SharedPreferences when I remove app on Android 6

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

When I delete app from a device with standard removing-methods (drag-and-drop for example) my `SharedPreferences` doesn't clean.

Why?

How to clean my `SharedPreferences`?

P.S. If I clear data in `Setting` manual `SharedPreferences` cleaned, but this isn't a solution for me.

Comment: Impossible !! ,just cross check the preference value at the starting time of the application after un-install it manually.

Comment: *with standart removing-methods*, you mean uninstalling it, right ?

Comment: @Radhey I said this my QA, but it's reproduce on two android devices!

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, simple removing, without clear data in Settings...

Comment: sorry, it is just to understand if we are on the same page. You are uninstalling the app, and the OS is still keeping the old SP's file ? On which devices does it happen ?

Comment: try adding `allowBackup="false"` in your manifest (application tag)

Comment: @Blackbelt - on Nexus 4 (CyanogenMode, 6 android), Samsung j7

Comment: @Blackbelt - write as answer - allowBackup="false"

Comment: @Blackbelt this worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to clean my SharedPreferences?

What are you experiencing is the default behavior of `allowBackup`, whch is `true` by default. From the documentation:

> Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and
>   restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup
>   or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a
>   full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to
>   be saved via adb. The default value of this attribute is true.

if you want to disable it add `allowBackup="false"` to the Application tag on your `AndroidManifest`. This way the `SharedPreferences` won't be restored

Comment: Yes, it is the problem!